# how to scale microservice (service fabric) instance when queue length increass

Tags: azure, scale, microservices, azure-service-fabric

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-scale/

But how can I scale up my microservice when queue length increases. have any inbuild way in azure service fabric ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time service fabric does not support autoscale, it will in the near future:

[service-fabric-cluster-scale-up-down](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-scale-up-down/)

> Auto-scale Service Fabric clusters
>
> At this time, Service Fabric clusters do not support auto-scaling. In the near future, clusters will be built on top of virtual machine scale sets, at which time auto-scaling will become possible and will behave similarly to the auto-scale behavior available in cloud services.

Answer (score 4):

[Update] Microsoft just released the new Service Fabric SDK (1.5.175), with support for Azure Scale Sets.   Ref: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2016/02/23/service-fabric-sdk-v1-5-175-and-the-adoption-of-virtual-machine-scale-sets/

Comment: From the linked blog: "Note that the auto-scaling functionality of VMSS is not integrated with Service Fabric yet and will be enabled in an upcoming release."